# how to grep by date time range?

Tags: python, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a log file looks like:

```
2011-03-21 00:01 xxxx
2011-03-22 04:05 xxxx
....
2011-03-25 10:12 xxxx
....
2011-04-04 12:23 xxxx
```

I want to have a script which requires 2 arguments as the date range, for example:

```
grep-date-range.sh 2011-03-25 2011-04-02
```

It will find all logs in [2011-03-25, 2011-04-02]. I know for a specific case i can use wildcard, but it's not general in my opinion. Could someone give me a solution?

**EDIT:** 
Python script is also acceptable.

Comment: You can probably chain together some super complex bash/cut/sed/awk script to do what you want. But if you know python or perl it would probably be easier just to write a small script that parses the first three numbers in each line and compares it to the range given in the arguments.

Comment: I'm really surprised by how hard this is to do as a shell script. The biggest blocker seems to be that there's no way to get date to accept a seconds-since-1970 input. WTF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

his is a case where it may be better to write  a short Python script. The high level date  manipulations capabilities in thelanguage can be handy.

The script bellow is very simple - with a bit more work it could take care of localtime differences, Daylight saving time, and so on.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
from datetime import datetime
d_format = "%Y-%m-%d"

try:
    start = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], d_format)
    end = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[2], d_format) 
except (TypeError, IndexError):
    sys.stderr.write("Example: grep-date-range.py 2011-03-25 2011-04-02 \n")

for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(line.split()[0], d_format)
        # suit the <=, <, comparisons bellow to your needs:
        if start <= date < end:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        pass
```

Comment: datetime.strptime is not found in my python. i can use time.strptime.

Comment: Todd: did you do from `datetime import datetime` ? datetime happens to be a factory function inside the datetime module. If you simply import datetime, then you have to use `datetime.datetime.strptime` - this is pretty standard, and certainly works in your Python.

Comment: Sorry - Just checked the docuemtnation, this was added in Python 2.5 (which is already some 6 or 7 seven years old, if you have any system with software older than that you serioulsy should think aboud upgrading). Anyway, the workaround for older Python versions is: `datetime.datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string, format)[0:6]))`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n "/$1/,/$2/p" $3
```

call it:

```
fromTo "2011-03-25" "2011-04-02" foo.log
```

sed

- -n: no output
- /from/,/to/: pattern to match
- p: print

The dates must exist in the file, it will not work if you just have 2011-03-24 and 2011-03-26 as date inside. It's string-matching, not date-matching. 
You don't need quoting, but I happened to have another date format, so I had for my tests ("Mar 23" and so on).

Comment: Just a small note, this will not work if dates are not sorted.

Comment: Yes, but the example logfile looks sorted, as most logfiles avoid travelling in time.

Comment: that's why i said its just a small note :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally got this. The basic idea is to merge the given dates in using the `sort -m`, the extract those known lines back out using sed (thanks to "user unknown"'s suggestion). If the data file isn't already sorted, sort it first. The assumption here is that the YYYY-MM-DD is a constant, otherwise this won't work.

You could probably make this more robust by using `mktemp` instead of `/tmp/startstop` and a more unique string than "START" and "END".

`/tmp/data` is obviously your data file.

```
#!/bin/bash

START=$1
END=$2

echo $START START > /tmp/startstop
echo $END END >> /tmp/startstop

sort -m /tmp/data /tmp/startstop | sed -n '/START/,/END/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

well, since you date is already "sortable",

```
#!/bin/bash

a=2011-03-25
b=2011-06-02
a=${a//-/} # you can remove the dashes or not, up to you
b=${b//-/} # you can remove the dashes or not, up to you
awk -va=$a -vb=$b '{
    # save the first field if going to remove dash, 
    old=$1 
    # you can remove the dashes or not, up to you. Because your date is sortable
    # the dash will not matter.
    gsub(/-/,"",old) # for removing dash
    if( old >= a && old <=b ){ 
        # or use if ($1 >=a && $1 <=b ) (if not removing dash)
        print
    }
}' file
```

Comment: stripping the dashes adds a lot of needless complexity: `awk -v a=2011-03-25 -v b=2011-04-02 'a <= $1 && $1 <= b'`

Comment: @glenn, in his case, there is no need to, as i have also indicated. BUT  if the dates are not "searchable" , then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, if your log is managed by journalctl, you just need

```
 journalctl -S 2011-03-25 -U 2011-04-02 (...)
```

From `man journalctl`:

> -S, --since=, -U, --until=
>
> Start showing entries on or newer than the specified date, or on or older than the specified date, respectively. Date specifications should be of the format "2012-10-30 18:17:16". If the time part is omitted, "00:00:00" is assumed. If only the seconds component is omitted, ":00" is assumed. If the date component is omitted, the current day is assumed. Alternatively the strings "yesterday", "today", "tomorrow" are understood, which refer to 00:00:00 of the day before the current day, the current day, or the day after the current day, respectively.  "now" refers to the current time. Finally, relative times may be specified, prefixed with "-" or "+", referring to times before or after the current time, respectively. For complete time and date specification, see systemd.time(7). Note that --output=short-full prints timestamps that follow precisely this format.