# how to use grep to filter out rows that contain dates that are before a certain day

Tags: linux, grep

I have a sample employee data file, and I want to filter out the rows where the **Employement_Status** column is **INACTIVE** and the **Hire_Date** is before **2013 June 1st**.

The rows in the file look like this

```
FirstName    LastName     BirthDate    EmploymentStatus    HireDate
  Tom           Red       5/16/1956        INACTIVE        4/13/1999
 Sandy         Green      12/21/1973       INACTIVE        12/20/2013
 John          Yellow     11/15/1983        ACTIVE         8/17/2000
```

And the grep command should only remove the second row.

Thank you very much

Comment: grep only can't do this. Seems like you need to have awk or perl.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it with awk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to grep by date time range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533671/how-to-grep-by-date-time-range)

Answer (score 2):

Not a one-liner solution, but:

filter.awk:

```
BEGIN {
  FS  = " "
  year  = 2013
  month  = 6
}
{
  split($5, a, "/")
  if( $4=="INACTIVE" && ((a[3] < year) || ((a[3] == from) && (a[1] < month)))) print $0;
}
```

call it like that:

```
awk -f filter.awk <your-example-file>
```

result:

```
FirstName    LastName     BirthDate    EmploymentStatus    HireDate
  Tom           Red       5/16/1956        INACTIVE        4/13/1999
```

UPDATE it seems I misunderstood the words "filter out" in OP. If the intention is to remove the rows with the given condition, then one can invert the statement:

```
if(!( $4=="INACTIVE" && ((a[3] < year) || ((a[3] == from) && (a[1] < month))))) print $0;
```

which gives the result:

```
FirstName    LastName     BirthDate    EmploymentStatus    HireDate
 Sandy         Green      12/21/1973       INACTIVE        12/20/2013
 John          Yellow     11/15/1983        ACTIVE         8/17/2000
```

Answer (score 1):

```perl
function op(qr) {
  split(qr, st, "/")
  return sprintf("%d%02d%02d", st[3], st[1], st[2])
}
NR > 1 &&
$4 == "INACTIVE" &&
op($5) < op("6/1/2013") {next}
1
```

Run like this

```
awk -f infile.awk infile.txt
```

Result

```
FirstName    LastName     BirthDate    EmploymentStatus    HireDate
 Sandy         Green      12/21/1973       INACTIVE        12/20/2013
 John          Yellow     11/15/1983        ACTIVE         8/17/2000
```